# how i can fix this error on wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I tried to translate the [search form](https://www.tecnologiageek.com/) to Spanish and I have this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/a/r/i/arismendy4444/html/wp-content/themes/passion/searchform.php on line 5

**MY CODE**

```
<form method="get" id="<?php echo "search-form-" . rand(0, 9999); ?>" class="search-form clearfix" action="<?php echo trailingslashit(home_url()); ?>"> <input autocomplete="off" type="text" onBlur="if ('' === this.value) this.value = this.defaultValue;" onFocus="if (this.value === this.defaultValue) this.value = '';" value="<?php _e('Keyword,kopa_get_domain()); ?>" name="s" class="search-text" maxlength="20"> <button type="submit" class="search-submit"><?php echo KopaIcon::getIcon('fa fa-search'); ?></button>
```

Comment: can you at least provide the code?

Comment: code:<form method="get" id="<?php echo "search-form-" . rand(0, 9999); ?>" class="search-form clearfix" action="<?php echo trailingslashit(home_url()); ?>">                            
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" onBlur="if ('' === this.value)
                this.value = this.defaultValue;" onFocus="if (this.value === this.defaultValue)
                            this.value = '';" value="<?php _e('Keyword,kopa_get_domain()); ?>" name="s" class="search-text" maxlength="20">
    <button type="submit" class="search-submit"><?php echo KopaIcon::getIcon('fa fa-search'); ?></button>

Answer (score 1):

Google would have returned a ton of answers on how to debug and fix the error you're receiving. `unexpected T_STRING` stands for a block of text that cannot be interpreted by PHP correctly, and the error message even states the exact line where the error originates from. You should first try and check the line for typos, unclosed quotes, parentheses and missing semicolons.

Anyways, you're missing a single-quote (`'`) right after `Keyword` and right before the comma:

```
<?php _e('Keyword,kopa_get_domain()); ?>
                ^^
```

which makes the parser spit out the error as it thinks that the single-quoted text continues on infitely and breaks because the PHP end tag is found before the end of the quote. The SO highlighter should illustrate this as the string highlight goes on until the PHP end tag (`?>`).

Additonally, `gettext` domains in translation functions (e.g. `__()` and `_e()`) should be implemented as static strings, as gettext parses PHP files as plain text (sort of) with no PHP parsing. This means the text domain in this template will be in `kopa_get_domain()` instead of `kopadomain` for instance. So the piece of code should be something like

```
<?php _e('Keyword', 'kopadomain')); ?>
```

Though I presume you're working with a premade theme as a base so it is the theme developers mistake in this case.

Comment: Thanks, yes the theme is from studi press, any sugestion to do, here is the theme instale, maybe you can hel me with this: https://www.tecnologiageek.com/